# Why Html.DropDownListFor requires extra cast?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, html-helper, viewdata

In my controller I create a list of **SelectListItems** and store this in the **ViewData**.  When I read the ViewData in my View it gives me an error about incorrect types.  If I manually cast the types it works but seems like this should happen automatically.  Can someone explain?

*Controller*:

```
enum TitleEnum { Mr, Ms, Mrs, Dr };
var titles = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach(var t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TitleEnum)))
  titles.Add(new SelectListItem() 
    { Value = t.ToString(), Text = t.ToString() });

ViewData["TitleList"] = titles;
```

*View*:

```
// Doesn't work
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, ViewData["TitleList"])

// This Works
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, (List<SelectListItem>) ViewData["TitleList"])
```

Comment: just use: `@Html.DropDownList("TitleList")` in view, that will work without extra casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ViewData` is a `Dictionary<string, Object>`. How else could you store objects of multiple types in a keyed collection? Anything retrieved from `ViewData` without casting will be treated by the compiler as a base `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, ViewData is an array/collection of objects. This is why the extra cast is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the compiler will not perform a cast from an object of type *object* to another type automatically.  I expect that results from ViewData are of type object at compile time.  Example follows:

```
// This Fails
object obj = new List<SelectListItem>();
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, obj);

// This Works
var obj2 = new List<SelectListItem>();
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of a feature called "static typing". Some love it, others hate it.

Answer (score -1):

what if you change

```
ViewData["TitleList"] = titles;
```

to

```
ViewData["TitleList"] = new SelectListItem() 
    { Value = t.ToString(), Text = t.ToString() };
```

and again try it with:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, ViewData["TitleList"])
```

if this works, the I would agree with Femaref....good question though.